# Set builder notation, (basic block problem).

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to represent a basic block with set-builder notation. Basic block is just a set of instructions and the instructions order is important here.

Can someone help me to figure out the correct solution?

Instruction = $I$

1)  Basic Block = b = {$ x | x = I$}

2)  Basic Block = b = {$(x_{1},x_{2} ... x_{k}) |\forall x_{i}, x_{i} = I, 0\le x_{i} \le k$}

--
**Edit 1:**

I = {A set of all possible instructions}

b = {$(x_{1},x_{2} ... x_{k}) |\forall x_{i}, x_{i} \in I, 0\le i \le k$}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set is the wrong data structure for your application. You want any of the equivalent notions of:

- a $(k+1)$-long sequence
- a $(k+1)$-tuple
- a function whose domain is the integers in $[0,k]$

Also, $x_i=I$ is surely not what you meant. You probably meant something along the lines of

- $I$ is the *set of possible instructions* and you mean $x_i \in I$
- You mean the predicate "$x$ is an instruction"

Comment: I is an instruction, not set of instructions. A basic block is basically a sequence of instructions. I am not sure how to represent this.

Comment: "A basic block is a sequence of instructions with indices $0, 1, \cdots, k$" is a perfectly good way to represent it. "It is an element of $\mathcal{I}^{k+1}$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is the set of all possible instructions" is a more algebraic way to represent it, if you really need an algebraic representation. If $I$ is a particular instruction, then defining a sequence by $x_i = I$ for $i=0, \cdots, k$ is not very useful... unless your basic block is supposed to be $(k+1)$ copies of the same instruction!

Comment: I see why x_i = I is not correct. Here 'I' represents only one instruction. Thanks for pointing out. I think, I will go for I = {a set of all instructions} . This set is infinite. And then x_i belongs to I for above expression.

Comment: Can you have a look on edited version?

Comment: @user: The $b$ you have now defined is the set of all possible $k$-tuples of instructions, rather than simply being a single $k$-tuple of instructions.

Comment: Then it should be $\{ x \colon x \in I \}$. But in this way, it does not represent the order.

Comment: @user: That is just the set $I$. Like I said above, trying to make a block a set is really the wrong way to do things. You *can* do it, but only in an artificial way that is only really useful to people who want to show that higher concepts can be modeled with set-theoretic foundations.

Comment: And looking at it again, I think you have a fundamental idea wrong; I think what you're really trying to express is that a block is a sequence and "each component of my sequence is an instruction", which really has nothing to do with set builder notation.

Comment: You are right. I cannot represent it as a set. I am looking into  'tuple of k-instructions' notations. Thanks for your help by the way.

Answer (score 1):

As you said that ordering is important, so 1) is obviously not the correct solution because any instruction will belong to b and ordering is not important in that case.

2) is absolutely fine but what you have written that, $0\le x_{i}\le k$, I think you have done a mistake here instead of $x_{i}$ you only have to write $i$.

Comment: I don't really think (2) means what the OP intends.